# Binomial Distributions Problem

Tags: probability, self-study, variance, binomial-distribution

A casino customer bets on red at roulette (probability of success is 9/19). If the result is red, the client is given 3 dollars; but if she loses, she pays 3 dollars. The client plays until she has won 5 of these bets.
What is the variance of her earnings?

I understand that it refers to the variance of a negative binomial but I wonder if to find the variance of the earnings I have to subtract the variance of the losses from the variance of the winnings?

Answer (score 0):

The Player's winning is 15 dollars which is a constant, so the winning's variance is zero.

In your case with the numbers you provided, the variance of his earning is

$\frac{3^2\times5p}{(1-p)^2}=\frac{45p}{(1-p)^2}=105.5556$, where $p=10/19$.